# getting bug fix for RHEL6

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel, upgrade

How can I get the new kernel as mentioned [here](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2015-1827.html)? I have a RHEL6 server that's using subscription manager and also registered with RHN. I have ran the usual yum updates and still am not getting the option for this kernel update although the advisory says its available.

Comment: Have you checked whether the update is listed in RHN? If so perhaps cleaning the cache helps?

Comment: @Bram what do you mean listed in RHN? You mean does yum find it when I do a "yum update"?. Yes I did a "yum clean all" to flush the cache with no luck.

Comment: If you log on to the red hat web site and open the subscribed system does it list the update you are looking for? We use a satellite server so I don't know precisely how systems are usually registered. Please update your question to include the output of yum search kernel and yum check-update. As well as yum repolist.

Comment: Interestingly, its installed. Not sure how or who did it. I am the only one with rights to update this sever and I can find no evidence of a user account running the command to update the kernel. Does RHEL have a way of reaching out to Red Hat to get kernel updates automatically?

Comment: Classic subscription management certainly had a feature to support automatic applying of errata. I don't know the exact details but I doubt it would apply only a kernel update. And even more that it would apply it only after a number of days. I suspect it was installed in a previous update run.